# How to disable p:defaultCommand when blockUI is active?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, blockui

I am using Primefaces 7.0 and want to disable the *defaultCommand* when the *blockUI* is active... My Problem is, when i hit the *SaveButton* the *blockUI* is active, but i can still press ENTER and the *defaultCommand* gets triggered. How can i disable this? I dont want to disable the *defaultCommand* always.

```
<h:form id="form">  

    <p:panel id="pnlContent">
        <p:commandButton value="SaveButton" id="btnSave" action="#{defaultView.longRunningOperation}"/>

        <p:defaultCommand target="btnSave"/>
    </p:panel>

    <p:blockUI block="pnlContent" trigger="btnSave"/>

</h:form>
```

Comment: The problem seemes to be that inputs or the triggering command button do not lose focus when blockUI gets active. You can see this even in the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml), a p:defaultCommand is not required to reproduce it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drop the focus from all components within the blocked panel by invoking `JQuery.blur()` on them:

```
<p:commandButton value="SaveButton" id="btnSave"
    onclick="$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:pnlContent') + ' *').blur()" />
```

This will prevent additional command invocations on subsequent pressing of `enter`.

Comment: Shouldn't `('form:pnlContent'+' *')` be `('form:pnlContent')+' *'`?

Comment: Awesome... it works! Didnt think of a focus problem in the first place. Thank you guys!